# barryvdh/laravel-dompdf renders blank web page

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I'm upgrading from Laravel 7 to 8 and would like to switch to `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` for PDF generation. I was using `niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf` up until now, but since that package doesn't support Laravel 8, I need to switch. So I am in the processing of altering my existing code to use `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`, but I'm running into an issue.

This is my (simplified) controller:

```
public function update(Request $request) {
    $invoice = Invoice::find($request->invoice_id);
    if(isset($request->export) AND $request->export == 1) {
        $this->exportInvoice($invoice, $request);
    }
}
```

This `exportInvoice` function is in the same controller file.

I'm using this to generate a test PDF:

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
return $pdf->stream();
```

Now I've managed to narrow down the issue to the place in my code where the PDF generation fails.

If I put the PDF generation code in the `if` statement in the update function above, then I get the expected result: a simple PDF file.

However, as soon as I move this piece of code to the `exportInvoice` function, I get a simple blank web page.

I've been googling around, but I was unable to find similar issues.

I've tried putting all my code together in the `update` function and guess what ... This works as expected. It's as if I'm doing something wrong with the subfunctions, but I can't figure out what.

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `update()` method, this will stream a PDF back to the browser:

```
return $pdf->stream();
```

But from a `exportInvoice()`, called by the `update()` method, that will just return the stream back to the `update()` method.  If you don't do anything with it there, it won't reach the browser.  You need to *return* the response returned from `exportInvoice()`.

```
public function update(Request $request) {
    $invoice = Invoice::find($request->invoice_id);
    if(isset($request->export) AND $request->export == 1) {
        // Note we need to *return* the response to the browser
        return $this->exportInvoice($invoice, $request);
    }
}

public function exportInvoice($invoice, $request) {
    $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```